# Flask Manager Command @manager.command doesn't work

Tags: flask, initialization, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a problem here.
I want to populate a table in the database with a record when the migration is executed, but actually it doesn't work. I'm using SQLAlchemy for the DB and the Manager object to create the DB.

In the DB I have a table called 'skills' which contains objects of type 'Skill'.
I just want to fill the table with a record during the initialization phase.
Please help me in finding the solution.

manage.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
from app import create_app, db
from app.models import Skill
from flask_script import Manager, Shell
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand

app = create_app(os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG') or 'default')
manager = Manager(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

def make_shell_context():
    return dict(app=app, db=db, Skill=Skill)

manager.add_command("shell", Shell(make_context=make_shell_context))
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)

@manager.command
def create_skill():
    db.session.add(Skill(name='ciaociao', in_use=False))
    db.session.commit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

init.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager
from config import config

db = SQLAlchemy()

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.session_protection = 'strong'
login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'

def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    config[config_name].init_app(app)

    db.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)

    return app
```

models.py

```
class Skill(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'skills'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True)
    in_use = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
```

Comment: What is the traceback?

Comment: There is NO traceback but the problem is that the database is not filled with the record. It is still void